# woocommerce product addon - empty cart upon going to product page

Tags: php, woocommerce, cart

Right now I am trying to get it so that whenever someone gets to my site's product page their cart is automatically emptied.

I am using a woocommerce product addon called "Product & Checkout Options for WooCommerce" that allows me to use radiobuttons/checkboxes for my products, I don't know if that will alter any of the code.

I've tried php code such as this but it hasn't worked:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'only_one_in_cart' , 10, 1);

function only_one_in_cart( $cart_item_data ) {
   global $woocommerce;
   $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
   unset($cart_item_data['product_meta']);
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Did it worked? select my answer if it worked

Answer (score 0):

It's better to add the hook on your single product page, do it with the action `woocommerce_before_single_product`:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', `only_one_in );
function only_one_in_cart() {
   global $woocommerce;
   $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
}
```

This will empty your cart each time you visit the page, if it's late, then you can add the function into the `wp_head` hook and validate if you are in the product page by `is_product()`:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', `only_one_in );
function only_one_in_cart() {
   if ( is_product() ){
      global $woocommerce;
      $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
   }
}
```